# What to do if the critical point is not a real number?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a function and I already differentiate it, but when I put it equals to zero I don't get a real number. What am I doing wrong?

$f(x) = x\sqrt{x^2+1}$

$f'(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}+\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+1})}$

$f'(x) = \frac{2x^2+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Then I equalizes it to 0

$\frac{2x^2+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=0$

$2x^2+1=0$

$2x^2=-1$

$x^2=-1/2$

So I don't know what to do next.

When reach the second derivative I get the same problem. What it means?

Comment: It means that there are no extrema. $f$ is in fact increasing on its entire domain.

Answer (score 2):

This function does not have a critical point. Notice that $f'(x)=\frac{2x^{2}+1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. So the function $f$ is a  monotonic increasing function.

If you are doing this for finding maxima of minima, then the answer is *maxima or minima do not exist on $\mathbb{R}$*. However if you restrict your attention on a compact interval (like $[a,b]$), then the absolute maxima and absolute minima of $f$ on $[a,b]$ are respectively $f(b)$ and $f(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The test for stationary points is like this:

> **If** $f$ has a stationary point at $x$, **then**  $f'(x)=0$.

So if $f'(x)$ isn't zero for **any** $x$, what would that mean?

Comment: From the statement you provided alone, I don't think we could gather much. Saying that if NOT "$f(x)=0$" then NOT "$f$ has a stationary point at x" is the contrapositive of the statement's converse

Comment: Of course! Sorry, that should be the other way round - I'll correct it.